# How to calculate stand deviation and mean

Tags: matlab

I have arrange my code in ascending order. I need to do a normal distribution of the data. I need to have random8 and random 24. I doubt array of small medium and large can do normal distribution and also finding the mean and standard deviation. Therefore how can i do for random 8 and random24
Below are my codes:

```
    symbols = {'SMALL', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE'};
    range = 101;  % <-- Or 101 if you want from 0 to 100 with 100 included
    rndInd = randi(numel(symbols), range ,1);
     st = symbols(rndInd);
    strjoin(st);
    random24 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str( randi(24, range, 1) )));
     random8 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str( randi(8, range, 1) )));
    b = num2cell(sort(randi(24, range, 1)));
     B = cellfun(@num2str, b, 'UniformOutput', false);
    %B = sort(random24)
     st = [ st' B random8 ]

     %% MEAN 

     mean8=mean(random8);
     fprintf( 'Mean of Random 8 parking Duration is %f',mean8);

      mean24=mean(random24);
      fprintf( 'Mean of Random 24 Hours is %f',mean24);

      %% Standard deviation
      standDev8= std(random8);
      fprintf( 'Standard Deviation of Random 1-8 Hours of  parking Duration             is %f',standDev8);
      figure(1);
      histogram(random8);
      title('Histogram of Data for Random 1-8 Hours of parking Duration')

      standDev24= std(random24);
      fprintf( 'Standard Deviation of Random 24 Hours is %f',standDev24);
      figure(2);
      histogram(random24);
      title('Histogram of Data for Random 24Hours ')
```

Error message i getting
         Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

```
     Error in mean (line 116)
       y = sum(x, dim, flag)/size(x,dim);

      Error in RANDOM (line 15)
       mean8= mean(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sorting a string rather than a number. That is why you are getting the result you see. One simple solution would be to first sort the array of numbers and then convert it into a list of strings.

So, your first part of the script can be unchanged:

```
symbols = {'SMALL', 'MEDIUM', 'LARGE'};
N = 101;  % <-- Or 101 if you want from 0 to 100 with 100 included
rndInd = randi(numel(symbols), N ,1);
st = symbols(rndInd);
strjoin(st);
```

You can leave the following line unchanged as well if you do not need to do anything with it:

```
rnd8 = strtrim(cellstr(num2str( randi(8, N, 1) )));
```

Then you can do something like this (maybe there are better alternatives out there):

```
b = num2cell(sort(randi(24, N, 1)));
B = cellfun(@num2str, b, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

And then keep your last line to check the output:

```
st = [ st' B rnd8 ]
```